# Do I understand the memory problems with this malloc/free combo?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, malloc

I have a c function that looks like this

```
void fn(void *data) {

    type *p=malloc(sizeof *p);
    p=data;
     ...
    free(p);
}
```

If I understand correctly, the two problems with this are that the `malloc` sets aside some memory for **p**, but the pointer in **p** is then immediately overwritten by the pointer **data** so nothing is pointing to the memory allocated to **p**. Also, the subsequent `free` actually frees the memory at **data** so that whatever function called **fn** will no longer be able to safely access it. Is this right?

What I probably meant to do is:

```
void fn(void *data) {

    type *p;
    p=data;
     ...
}
```

Since there's no `malloc` there's nothing to `free` and the pointer in **data** continues to point to allocated memory?

EDIT: I should point out that I know for sure that the pointer in **data** is actually a pointer of the same type as **p**.

FURTHER EDIT: The pointer in **data** points to something that was malloc'd elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that seems right.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Put an example on how you are calling the function "fn" to give us a better idea

Comment: @RenanGreinert my use case is complex. I am actually passing a `type *` to a library which is eventually calling **fn**. The library allows you to pass a `void *` that points to any data you want to access from **fn**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You understood right.  Assigning `data` to `p` after allocating memory to `p` will leave no pointer to the allocated memory by `malloc`.
A block of memory that's  no longer accessible to a program is said to be *garbage*. A program that leaves garbage behind has a **memory leak**.
Unfortunately, unlike some other languages, C doesn't have **garbage collector**.

<strike>Another thing is that calling `free(p)` will invoke **undefined behavior** because the argument to `free` *must be a pointer that was previously returned by a memory allocation function* (or it could be a `NULL` pointer).</strike>

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to track down a memory leak with valgrind and found something like this.

Comment: I think there is a typo... "Unfortunately" should read "Fortunately"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the function should not free the memory it did not allocate. The principle worth following in most cases is: do not allocate and deallocate in different contexts.

Comment: So the `p=data...free(p)` does, in fact deallocate **data**?

Comment: Yes it deallocates `data`.

Comment: @William Everett: It's not so simple nor obvious. If `data` is _null pointer_, then no action occurs, also if `data` doesn't point to result of `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` function, then you get UB.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSzpetkowski. I added some text indicating that `data` was malloc'd elsewhere.